# How to set a prefix for all print() output in python?

Tags: python, printing, formatting

I am printing to a console in python. I am looking for a one off piece of code so that all print statments after a line of code have 4 spaces at the start. Eg.

```
print('Computer: Hello world')
print.setStart('    ')
print('receiving...')
print('received!')
print.setStart('')
print('World: Hi!')
```

Output:

```
Computer: Hello world
    receiving...
    received!
World: Hi!
```

This would be helpful for tabbing all of the output that is contained in a function, and setting when functions output are tabbed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can define a `print` function which first prints your prefix, and then internally calls the built-in `print` function. You can even make your custom `print()` function to look at the call-stack and accordingly determine how many spaces to use as a prefix:

```
import builtins
import traceback

def print(*objs, **kwargs):
    my_prefix = len(traceback.format_stack())*" "
    builtins.print(my_prefix, *objs, **kwargs)
```

**Test it out:**

```
def func_f():
    print("Printing from func_f")
    func_g()

def func_g():
    print ("Printing from func_g")

func_f()
```

**Output:**

> ```
>                     Printing from func_f
>                      Printing from func_g
> ```

**Reverting back to the built-in `print()` function:**

When you are done with your custom printing, and want to start using the built-in `print()` function, just use `del` to "delete" your own definition of print:

```
del print
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not define your own custom function and use that when needed:

```
def tprint(*args):
    print('    ', *args)
```

It would be used like so:

```
print('Computer: Hello world')
tprint('receiving...')
tprint('received!')
print('World: Hi!')
```

Output:

```
Computer: Hello world
     receiving...
     received!
World: Hi!
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use specific prefixes only at specific places

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def add_prefix(prefix): 
    global is_new_line
    orig_write = sys.stdout.write
    is_new_line = True
    def new_write(*args, **kwargs):
        global is_new_line
        if args[0] == "\n":
            is_new_line = True
        elif is_new_line:
            orig_write("[" + str(prefix) + "]: ")
            is_new_line = False
        orig_write(*args, **kwargs)
    sys.stdout.write = new_write
    yield
    sys.stdout.write = orig_write
    
with add_prefix("Computer 1"):
    print("Do something", "cool")
    print("Do more stuffs")
    
with add_prefix("Computer 2"):
    print("Do further stuffs")
print("Done")

#[Computer 1]: Do something cool
#[Computer 1]: Do more stuffs
#[Computer 2]: Do further stuffs
#Done
```

The advantage is that it's a utility function, i.e. you just have to import to use it, without having to redefine every time you write a new script.